# Virtuoso SPARQL query slow on JavaScript fetch

Tags: javascript, browser, fetch, sparql

When I execute a SPARQL query over the browser or `curl`, it is much faster than in the same browser using JavaScript fetch. For example, `select * {?s ?p ?o.}` on DBpedia takes 400-1000 ms in the browser and several seconds using JavaScript fetch. The number of rows gets limited to 10000 in both cases (the complete DBpedia would be too large otherwise). This is not limited to DBpedia, it happens to our own SPARQL endpoint as well, which contains around 100k triples. I am using Firefox Developer Edition 65.0b3 (64-bit). How can I get the same performance or at least a similar one using `fetch`? To execute the MWE, CORS rules need to be bypassed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8"></head>
<body>
  <script>
 const ENDPOINT = "http://dbpedia.org/sparql"
 const GRAPH = "http://dbpedia.org";

 function sparql(endpoint, graph, query)
 {
   const url = endpoint +
   '?query=' + encodeURIComponent(query) +
   '&format=json'+
   '&default-graph-uri=' + encodeURIComponent(graph);
   return fetch(url);
 }
  const query = "select * {?s ?p ?o.}";
 sparql(ENDPOINT,GRAPH,query);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: Network Tab of the MWE]
[image: Network Tab of the query URL in Firefox]

Answer (score 1):

Look at the differences in the request headers (especially but perhaps not only `Accept: */*` vs `Accept: text/html,application/xhtml..., */*;q=0.8` ).

I believe if you make the [JS/fetch() request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) the same as the browser's, you'll find the response times will match.